# Plotting horizontal lines on Bode plot

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I have an array of transfer functions and plotted multiple Bode plot. Now I need to add a horizontal line to show where all these Bode plots attain a gain of -8db. I know that previously people replied similar type of questions for drawing vertical line. But it seems that the same method is not working for horizontal lines? I also tried to draw a separate line and then used Show with the Bode plot diagram. But it didn't work. To summarise, what I am looking for is shown in this image. [image] - I am trying to draw the black lines and mark the intersection points with different marker colours.
Could somebody help please?

Answer (score 2):

This is a `LogLinearPlot`. Let's use an example plot from the documentation and draw lines over it.

```
Ra[f_] := (
 12200^2 f^4)/((f^2 + 
    20.6^2) Sqrt[(f^2 + 107.7^2) (f^2 + 737.9^2)] (f^2 + 12200^2))

LogLinearPlot[Ra[f], {f, 10, 10^5}, GridLines -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> {
   {Thick, Black, Line[{{Log[1000], 0}, {Log[1000], Ra[10^3]}}]}
   , {Thick, Red, Line[{{Log[10^1], Ra[10^3]}, {Log[1000], Ra[10^3]}}]}
   , {AbsolutePointSize[8], Darker@Green, Point[{Log[1000], Ra[10^3]}]}
   }
 ]
```

[image]

If you have a more specific question, you can update your post and present a minimal example featuring copy-paste-able Mathematica code.

Comment: Hi Syed, Thank you so much. Here is the transfer function: TF = TransferFunctionModel[{{{
   1.8831584343714116`*^9 + 91654.79372668632 s}}, 
  2.3314280115350676`*^9 + 134019.32322803652` s + 1. s^2}, s]. I would like to have the green point at your example at (34453.1, -8.5193}  and draw the black and red lines in your example from that point.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`GridLines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) option, and [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) also if needed.

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[{{{1.8831584343714116*^9 + 91654.79372668632 s}}, 
    2.3314280115350676*^9 + 134019.32322803652` s + 1. s^2}, s];
pt = 10^5; 

BodePlot[tfm, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude", Mesh -> {{pt}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Green], 
    GridLines -> {{pt}, {20 Log10@Abs[tfm[I pt]][[1, 1]]}}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Directive[Red, Thick]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Suba, thank you so much. Really appreciate.